# How to access instance variable in partial from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, instance-variables

I'm stuck trying to access instance variables from one controller/view to another.

**ProductsController**

```
def index
  @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(include_images: true))
  @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
end
```

I want to gain access to `@products` in `_header.html.erb` partial, which is a part of the main layout page `application.html.erb`.

Comment: Which local variable are you having problem with? I don't see any.

Comment: My fault. Instance variable

Comment: @pfc And what if you render `header` for some other action, where `@products` is not defined?

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good practice to pass local variable inside a partial, to make it useable at more than one place. so you should pass `@products` inside a local variable in partial -

Unless i'm missing something variable should be `@products` instead of `@product` as `index` action has `@products`

```
= render partial: 'header', locals: {product: @product}
```

In _header.html.erb `product` local variable will be accessible which is `@product`

Comment: Let me reformulate question(maybe you haven't seen edit). I want to gain access of INSTANCE variable @products from products controller, index action. I need that in my _header partial view which is part of main layout of page